# Memos in python (Think Python exercise 11.6)

Tags: python, dictionary, fibonacci, memoization

In the Think Python book Chapter 11, Allen Downey mentions that "... a previously computed value that is stored for later use is called a *memo*" (p. 107).

The following function is then re-written to improve it by using *memos*:

```
def fibonacci(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)
```

The re-written function looks like the following:

```
known = {0: 0, 1: 1}

def memoized_fibonacci(n):
    if n in known:
        return known[n]
    res = fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)
    known[n] = res
    return res
```

I am wondering, why it is necessary to add the recursion call (here: 'res') to the dictionary (memo) before returning it.

If I print the dictionary after any call of fibonacci, the dictionary just contains the information that has been there before (0:0, 1:1) as well as the information for n:

```
>> memoized_fibonacci(7)
>> print known
>> {0: 0, 1: 1, 7: 13}
```

so no intermediate results are being saved that could be helpful to save time (memo). Using the time module, I furthermore can only gain a minimum time advantage of the memoized_fibonacci function over the simpler fibonacci function. (I.e. for memoized_fibonacci(40) I take 58.1 seconds and for fibonacci(40) I take 58.8 seconds)

Deleting the `known[n] = res` call does not slow the memoized function down either.

```
known = {0: 0, 1: 1}

def memoized_fibonacci(n):
    if n in known:
        return known[n]
    return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)    # Not slower!
```

Am I missing the point here? Could somebody explain to me, why calling `known[n] = res` is important? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that's the correct code? I'd expect the recursive calls to also be to the `memoized_` version (otherwise you're right, there's no benefit). This is why it's generally implemented as a function decorator, so you can replace the original version in-place with the memoized version.

Comment: You will see the benefit once you call memoized_fibonacci for all inputs smaller then your original n, and there will be some speed up also for future ns that are bigger. In other words if you calculated fibonacci(40), then all calls to fibonacci with 0 .. 39 should be instantaneous

Comment: @user1514631 no, there won't be much improvement, because only e.g. the `7` in the first example gets memoized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
known[res] = n
```

is needed otherwise you wont store the result in "known" and you will need to recalculate all the elements of the progression every time.

If you start with known = {0:0, 1:1}, after fibonacci(29) known will be populated with:

```
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 3, 5: 5, 6: 8, 7: 13, 8: 21, 9: 34, 10: 55, 11: 89, 12: 144, 13: 233, 14: 377, 15: 610, 16: 987, 17: 1597, 18: 2584, 19: 4181, 20: 6765, 21: 10946, 22: 17711, 23: 28657, 24: 46368, 25: 75025, 26: 121393, 27: 196418, 28: 317811, 29: 514229}
```

Then moving to fibonacci(30) is almost instantaneous because both fibonacci(29) and fibonacci(28) are in **known**.

Comment: Again this is a problem with the implementation, not the concept - *"no intermediate results are being saved"* because the recursive calls are to the original, unmemoized version of the function.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, yes there is a misconsecption because memoized:fibonacci is not recursive, but the idea with the speedup is exactly what I described

Comment: @jonrsharpe, once the definition of fibonacci is fixed, you get the speedup

Comment: You mean *"when I copy verbatim from your answer"*?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, yes all that text, the output dict until 29, plus the explanation why there is a benefit is a verbatim copy from your answer, you should put a copyright on your answer and sue everyone who reads it.

Comment: I've no problem with the first part of your answer (although it doesn't actually address the OP's specific issue), just [this revision](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/33019795/2). Everyone's posts here are released under Creative Commons (see http://stackexchange.com/legal), but that doesn't make plagiarism OK and certainly doesn't give you the right to get huffy when it's pointed out.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, before making the edit my answer didn't share even a word with yours. I just added the corrected version of the function which has to be identical to yours and to the one at the link you provided, just to make clear to the OP that he made a typo. This has nothing to do with plagiarism.

Comment: Note that the comment isn't in the book, which you also don't reference. *"just to make clear to the OP that he made a typo"* - which it doesn't. Again, *"before making the edit"* is irrelevant.

Answer (score 4):

You have made a typo. The code from [the book](http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/html/thinkpython012.html#toc125) is:

```
known = {0:0, 1:1}

def fibonacci(n):
    if n in known:
        return known[n]

    res = fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)  # note same name
    known[n] = res
    return res
```

If you rename the function (to `memoized_fibonacci`) you need to **change the recursive calls, too**. Otherwise the memoized version is calling the un-memoized version, and you don't get any benefit.